# cv2.ORB.detectAndCompute exits python

Tags: python, opencv

I have literally no idea what's going on here because I've never seen anything like this happen. I was working on a program for a school project, I ran my code and nothing really happened, after a certain point in the code the program just exited, no error code or anything.

I made sure nothing should be throwing errors and restarted my computer as well as uninstalling and reinstalling OpenCV but nothing worked.

```
img = process("image.jpg") #loads image using cv2.imread and converts to rgb
ih, iw = img.shape[:-1]
img10 = process("img10Test1.jpg")
h, w = img10.shape[:-1]

print("mark 1") #debugging
kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
kp10, des10 = orb.detectAndCompute(img10, None)
print("mark 2") #debugging
matches = bf.match(des, des10)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x.distance)
```

My output shows this:

```
mark 1

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>>
```

Why is orb.detectAndCompute not doing anything?

Comment: Where did you create the ORB detector?  `orb = cv2.ORB_create()`?  Your code assumes this was created but it's nowhere to be found.